# jQuery - removeClass not working properly

Tags: jquery, colors, styles, removeclass

I do not know how i can change the code, that the removeClass function can do his job. At the moment, this function is not working (i think so). The biggest problem is this:

When i am clicking menu item "1", than black box appears, and menu item "1" text color becomes blue. It is logical to assume, that when i am clicking menu item "2", than the first menu item "1" color become black (not blue), and the second menu item "2", color becomes blue. However, both of them are blues.

Small part of code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#icons').click(function () {
    $('#chat-drop,#chat-drop2').hide()
        if ($('#chat-drop').is(":visible")) {
            $('#chat-drop').hide()
        $('#rodyti').removeClass('active');
        } else {
            $('#chat-drop').show()
        $('#rodyti').addClass('active');
        }
    return false;
});
```

Full code: http://jsfiddle.net/wW75v/9/

I would be grateful for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem seems to be that you are doing the removeClass() when #chat-drop is(":visible"), but it will not go inside that if because you've just hidden #chat-drop in the previous line.

You can add the removeClass() to both rodyti and rodyti2 so they are removed always. But be aware that the is(":visible") is quite useless if you trigger hide() just above it.

Comment: I will be grateful if you will help me with remaking of this code. In wich place, i should put removeclass code?

Comment: Thank you very much for the help! It works absolutely fine, as i wanted to.

Answer (score 1):

Just a suggestion, in place of using `id` you can use `class`. It would reduce your code like:

**FROM**

```
<div id="icons">
    <div id="rodyti">1</div>
    <div id="chat-drop">Menu1</div>
</div>
<div id="icons2">
    <div id="rodyti2">2</div>
    <div id="chat-drop2">Menu2</div>
</div>
```

**TO:**

```
<div class="icons">
    <div class="rodyti">1</div>
    <div class="chat-drop">Menu1</div>
</div>
<div class="icons">
    <div class="rodyti">2</div>
    <div class="chat-drop">Menu2</div>
</div>
```

**JS CODE FROM**

```
$('#icons').click(function () {
    $('#chat-drop,#chat-drop2').hide()
    // Your code here..
    return false;
});


$('#icons2').click(function () {
    $('#chat-drop,#chat-drop2').hide()
    // Your code here..
    return false;
});
```

**TO JUST THIS**

```
$('.icons').click(function () {
    $('.chat-drop').hide()
    // Your code here..
    return false;
});
```